# Retrofit + RxJava doesn't return anything after network call

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

So here's my code

```
RestAdapter restAdapter=new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(HelperFunctions.BASE_URL).build();
final ApiInterface apiInterface=restAdapter.create(ApiInterface.class);

apiInterface.submitDataToAnalyze("dataToAnalyze", "852741963", 1, uuid, dataToAnalyze.toString(), todayDate)
.onErrorReturn(new Func1<Throwable, BasicResponse>() {
    @Override
    public BasicResponse call(Throwable throwable) {
        Log.e(FILE_NAME, "masuk sini??");
        return null;
    }
 })
 .flatMap(new Func1<BasicResponse, Observable<LocationSuggestion>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<LocationSuggestion> call(BasicResponse basicResponse) {
        Log.v(FILE_NAME, "basicResponse: " + basicResponse.toString());
        return Observable.just(null);
                                    }
    })
 .map(new Func1<LocationSuggestion, Integer>() {
      @Override
      public Integer call(LocationSuggestion suggestion) {
          Log.v(FILE_NAME, "eh sampai sini");
          return 1;
      }
  }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

None of my log was displayed in the logcat. What should I do to know if my network call (and all other subsequant flatmap or map) is working correctly? Btw apiInterface.submitDataToAnalyze() should insert some data into a remote database (which in this case it didn't insert anything, hence I'm trying to figure out where the error happened)

Comment: you never subscribe to your observable...

Comment: I thought the apiInterface handles that? Sorry in my POV, i'm still looking at this code purely from retrofit's view.

Comment: no. why would it? it returns a cold observable, so nothing happens until you subscribe to it. Consider this: `Observable.just("one").map(i -> {Log.d("Value", i); return i;});` does nothing on its own. You have to subscribe to it.

Comment: a simple call to `subscribe()` will trigger the api call.

Comment: Ok...thanks a lot @njzk2.. I was already reading back retrofix-rxjava tutorial. There's a lot more that I need to learn....